# How can I define an alias for a Git subcommand (e.g. for `list` in `git stash list`)?

Tags: git, alias, git-config

Whenever I try to type `git stash list` my fingers go rogue and type `git stash ls`.  I'd really like to alias ls to list, but only within the stash subcommand.  Is this possible with git aliases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git doesn't offer any mechanism for aliasing a subcommand; see the [`git-config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man page.

However, there is a trick for achieving the same effect: use a small wrapper around the `git` binary by defining a shell command also called `git` that does what you want:

```sh
git() {
    if [ "$1" = "stash" -a "$2" = "ls" ]
    then
        command git stash list
    else
        command git $@
    fi;
}
```

Not pretty, but does the job (as tested in one of my repositories):

```sh
# starting from a dirty working state...
$ git stash save
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 7c6655d add missing word in documentation
HEAD is now at 7c6655d add missing word in documentation
$ git stash ls
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 7c6655d add missing word in documentation
```

Note that this approach isn't very robust. In particular, `git stash list` will *not* be run if there are other command-line arguments between `git` and `stash ls`, as in

```sh
git -C ~/Desktop stash ls
```

The approach should be sufficient for your use case, though.

To avoid having to retype the definition of that `git` function every time you start your shell, you should put it in one of the files that your shell is configured to source.